# Hibernate 6, Postgres, and bytea

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

With the release of **Hibernate 6**, once again I am scratching my head trying to figure out how to get Hibernate to convert a **@Lob** to **bytea** for a **PostGres** database.  I also need the code to be testable with H2 (or any in memory database).

I am using Postgres 10+ (v13), so that takes care of that requirement.

This is what I used before, which was tricky, because I also needed it to work with H2.  (The PostGres dialect was only loaded in production, not tests.)

Sadly, getting bytea to work is "outside the scope" of the Hibernate 6 user guide. See 2.2.47.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

The migration guide also seems silent on the topic.
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc

The entire API for SQLDialect family has been rewritten, so I am back to square 1.

```
public class CustomPostgresSQL10Dialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect{

  public CustomPostgresSQL10Dialect() {
    super();
    registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "bytea");
  }

  @Override
  public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor) {
    if (sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType() == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
      return BinaryTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
    }

    return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to be sure, since you have not told us what the *Java* type of the field you're trying to map with the `@Lob` annotation is, but hell, just this once I'll have a go at reading your mind, and *speculate* that what you've written is this:

```
@Lob 
byte[] binaryData;
```

Now, the Postgres JDBC driver doesn't support using the LOB APIs to read/write `bytea` columns, and Hibernate knows about this, so it does the next-most-sensible thing, and assumes that this field maps to an `oid` column. This turns out to not be what you want.

Of course, you could try bypassing Hibernate's knowledge of Postgres by writing:

```
@Lob @Column(columnDefinition="bytea") 
byte[] binaryData;
```

And then you would get an error from Postgres or its driver (I forget which), because, as I said, the postgres driver doesn't support this.

So what to do?

Well, sure, you could try hacking the Hibernate `Dialect` as you have done above, to tell Hibernate to:

1. use `bytea` for the JDBC type `BLOB`, and
2. bind JDBC `BLOB`s using the usual handling for the JDBC type `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` or whatever.

And yeah, you could still make that work easily enough in H6.

Or, you know, *you could just remove the stupid `@Lob` annotation which isn't doing any useful work here*, and let Hibernate treat your field as a `varbinary`, which maps to `bytea` by default.

```
byte[] binaryData;
```

Now, look, there might be something more to what you're doing here, but then you'll need to help me out here by actually posting the details of the field and how you've mapped it.

Answer (score 4):

We had exactly the same problem and manage to fix it with this dialect class (kotlin):

```kotlin
class CustomSQLDialect : PostgreSQLDialect(DatabaseVersion.make(9, 5)) {
    override fun columnType(sqlTypeCode: Int): String {
        return when (sqlTypeCode) {
            SqlTypes.BLOB -> "bytea"
            else -> super.columnType(sqlTypeCode)
        }
    }

    override fun castType(sqlTypeCode: Int): String {
        return when (sqlTypeCode) {
            SqlTypes.BLOB -> "bytea"
            else -> super.castType(sqlTypeCode)
        }
    }

    override fun contributeTypes(typeContributions: TypeContributions, serviceRegistry: ServiceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry)
        val jdbcTypeRegistry = typeContributions.typeConfiguration
            .jdbcTypeRegistry
        jdbcTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(Types.BLOB, BinaryJdbcType.INSTANCE)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution makes little sense to me. You're just redefining `@Lob` to mean "not a LOB".

Comment: @Gavin-King The problem is that `@Lob` is for large binary objects. In Postgres, `@Lob` does not map to bytea, which may not be what you want to do, because Postgres basically has two binary Lob formats.  This preserves `@Lob` meaning to be large, indeterminant size.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, that I need to support `H2`,`MariaDB` and `PostgreSQL` at the same time. In addition to the original problem I also had to map `CLOB` to `text`. Based on the Kotlin solution, I have created this java class.

```
public class CustomPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {

    public CustomPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected String columnType(int sqlTypeCode) {
        if (SqlTypes.BLOB == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "bytea";
        }
        if (SqlTypes.CLOB == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "text";
        }
        return super.columnType(sqlTypeCode);
    }

    @Override
    protected String castType(int sqlTypeCode) {
        if (SqlTypes.BLOB == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "bytea";
        }
        if (SqlTypes.CLOB == sqlTypeCode) {
            return "text";
        }
        return super.castType(sqlTypeCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void contributeTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry);
        JdbcTypeRegistry jdbcTypeRegistry = typeContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getJdbcTypeRegistry();
        jdbcTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(Types.BLOB, BinaryJdbcType.INSTANCE);
        jdbcTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(Types.CLOB, LongVarcharJdbcType.INSTANCE);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is great, now we have Java code, too.  Thanks